# Takes exactly one argument, two given

Tags: python, button, graphics

```
from Graphics import *

win = Window()
button = Button ((200,100), "click")
button.draw(win)

score=100

def user_click(score):
    score+=10
    print(score)

button.connect('',user_click)
```

I want this function to add 10 points to the score. But I'm getting this error

> Takes exactly one argument, two given

How would I fix this bug to do that?

Comment: A full traceback would help, as well as specifying exactly what library you're using.

Comment: I'm assuming that the callback passes two variables to your callback function `user_click` neither of which is the score. You'll likely want to set the callback equal to a lambda. `button.connect('', lambda x,y: user_click(score))`

Comment: This isn't Tkinter. This could be PyGTK...What's the library you're using?

Comment: I'm just using the graphics library. I'm doing this for a school project and graphics is the only library we're allowed to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gui Element callbacks usually expect an argument called 'event', that's the second argument that you are passing into user_click.

Try this:

```
def user_click(event, score):
    score+=10
    print(score)
```

Comment: after I do that, I get another error that says 'unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Button' and 'int'.' Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: It sounds like the order of arguments passed into the function declaration. Try: def user_click(score, event) instead